# Facebook customer chat overflow / edit height?

Tags: css, facebook, height, overflow

I have a problem with Facebook customer chat. When it pop up on a laptop let's say smaller screens, chat jumps under the website header and menu bar. Is there any possibility to change fb customer chat height or any idea how to make it to be over the header and menu bar?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please try: `z-index: 9999999;` for chat container .

Comment: Thanks, works perfect with position:absolute;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap includes several components that function as an overlay of some kind. This includes, in order of highest z-index, dropdowns, fixed and sticky navbars, modals, tooltips, and popovers. These components have their own z-index scale that begins at 1000. This starting number is random and serves as a small buffer between our styles and your project’s custom styles.

> Each overlay component increases it’s z-index value slightly in such a
>   way that common UI principles allow user focused or hovered elements
>   to remain in view at all times.

So changing the Z-index value of chat box to a value greater than z-index of navbar might fix the issue.